# Download an entire Pinterest board

Tags: pinterest

I've got a Pinterest board that I don't own, but am able to access by browsing the URL.

Is there a way I can download the entire board, either natively or by some sort of extension?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Google Chrome extension called **Pinterest Enhanced**. That allows an easier way to download images with just on click. Pinterest updated their security settings so not many new things have appeared.